# magento 2 : Equivalent class for Adapter Product and Parser abstract

Tags: magento2, class

What is the equivalent class for the same in Magento2

> Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
>
> Mage_Eav_Model_Convert_Parser_Abstract